# Combine two regular expression that check an url into one

Tags: javascript, regex, subdomain

This is my code to check the url is subDomain or not .

```
    var domain_1 = "abc.mydomain.com";
    var domain_2 = "abc.localhost:44880"

    var regex1 = new RegExp(/^([a-z]+\:\/{2})?([\w-]+\.[\w-]+\.\w+)$/);
    var regex2 = new RegExp(/^([a-z]+\:\/{2})?([\w-]+\.[\w-]+\:\w+)$/);
   
    let result1 = !!domain_1.match(regex1);
    let result2 = !!domain_2.match(regex2);
```

As you can see, the format for first subDomain is like **###.###.###** (with two dots) second one is **###.###:###** (with one dot and one colon).
For those two format , I need two Regular Expressions.
Can I combine it to one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes care of single word (`localhost`) to many dot separated words (`abc.many.subs.mydomain.com`) for the domain name, making sure that there are no consecutive dots, followed by an optional port number (`:1234`) :

```js
const domains = [
  'abc.mydomain.com',
  'abc.localhost:44880',
  'localhost',
  'abc.many.subs.mydomain.com',
  'abc.my@domain.com',
  'abc.my@domain.com:1234'
];
const regex = /^[a-z_\-]+(\.[a-z_\-]+)*(\:[0-9]+)?$/;
domains.forEach((domain) => {
  var result = regex.test(domain);
  console.log(domain + ' ==> ' + result)
});
```

Console output:

```
abc.mydomain.com ==> true
abc.localhost:44880 ==> true
localhost ==> true
abc.many.subs.mydomain.com ==> true
abc.my@domain.com ==> false
abc.my@domain.com:1234 ==> false
```

Explanation:

- `^...$` - anchor regex at start and end
- `[a-z_\-]+` - start with a word of one or more allowed chars
- `(\.[a-z_\-]+)*` - followed by zero or more occurrences of a dot and a word
- `(\:[0-9]+)?` - followed by an optional dot and at least one digit

Comment: mydomain.com ==> true

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```js
const domain_1 = "abc.mydomain.com";
const domain_2 = "abc.localhost:44880"

const regex = new RegExp(/^([a-z]+\:\/{2})?([\w-]+\.[\w-]+((\.\w+)|(\:\d+)))$/);
   
const result1 = regex.test(domain_1);
const result2 = regex.test(domain_2);
console.log(result1, result2)
```

https://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/or-in-regex/

Comment: `RegExp` contructor need a string as argument, you give it a regex

Comment: No it is ok to give it a regex according to mdn documentation, the first argument of RegExp constructor is: The text of the regular expression or, as of ES5, another RegExp object (or literal) to copy (the latter for the two RegExp constructor notations only).